# Find whole word with strpos()

Tags: php, strpos

Hello people :)
I'm trying to use strpos() to find whole words in a sentence. But at the moment, it also find the word if it just are a part of another word. For example:

```
$mystring = "It's a beautiful morning today!";
$findme   = "a";

$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
```

In this example it would find "a" in the word "a" (as it should do), but also in "beautiful" because there is an a in it.

How can i find only whole words and not if it is a part of other words?

Comment: There' sdefinitely better methods to do this than using strpos(), so why the restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex , with the word boundary delimiter `\b`, like this :

```
$mystring = "It's a beautiful morning today!";
preg_match_all('/\ba\b/', $mystring, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches);
```

returns

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [1]=>
      int(5)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Xavier. I couldn't get this solution working. Have you other solutions?

Comment: I found out! If i just put space around the word, it done the work. Thanks for your time! ;)

Comment: Putting space around it doesn't detect it if its the first or last word of string.

Answer (score 13):

This is a job for regex:

```
$regex = '/\b'.$word.'\b/';
```

Basically, it's finding the letters surrounded by a word-boundary (the `\b` bits).  So, to find the position:

```
preg_match($regex, $string, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$pos = $match[0][1];
```

Comment: And if you're not sure where the word ends?. In my case it's a youtube url that might have a random query string attached to it, i just need the position of the beginning and the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

regex is hard for beginners, another way and I admit it isn't the best, would be to use
$findme   = " a "

Comment: I found out! If i just put space around the word, it done the work. Thanks for your time! ;)

Comment: That answer is wrong. It won't find word if it's the first or the last one.

Comment: @ElChupacabra "...and I admit it isn't the best"